# R-package Lattice: group by color doesn't work when using panel argument

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I would like to plot a xyplot with lines. As an example I'm using the iris data and I know the actual plot doesn't really make sense :)

```
library(lattice)

panel.iris <- function(x,y){
    panel.xyplot(x,y)
    panel.lines(x,y)
    }

xyplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width| Petal.Width, data = iris, groups= Species, 
auto.key=list(space="right"), panel=panel.iris)
```

This gives me the following figure:
[image: Iris xy plot with lines but without color by group]
But I actually want it to be colored by group, like so (but with added lines):
[image: Iris xy plot colored by group but without lines]
I can only achieve this when I'm not using the panel argument... Is there a way around this?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass on the `groups` and `subscripts` to the `panel.xyplot` function so that it know what colors go with each point like so:

```
panel.iris <- function(x,y,groups,subscripts){
  panel.xyplot(x,y,groups=groups, subscripts=subscripts)
  panel.lines (x,y)
}
```